# Как поменять меню в зависимости от ответа сервера?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Хотелось бы понять, возможно вопрос из области JavaScript, думаю,что это в его силах.

Есть у меня выпадающее меню сделанное на Bootstrape

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">Создать почтовый ящик</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Логин" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" id="LoginTextBox" runat="server" />
                                        <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">@fenixrostov.ru</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group" id="pass">
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Пароль" id="PassTextBox" runat="server" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                Статус: <asp:Label ID="Status" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Button ID="RegMail" runat="server" Text="Зарегистрировать" CssClass="btn btn-default" OnClick="RegMail_Click" />
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Вот сюда `Статус: <asp:Label ID="Status" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>` выводятся ответы с сервака. К примеру два варианта `Все ОК!` и `Все не ОК`,если будет `Все ок` как мне закрыть это модульное окно и вызвать другое?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(s = 'Все ОК!') {
   $('#myModal').modal('hide');
   $('otherModal').modal('show');
}
```

Comment: Я не далёк в Джавескрипт, как мне этот s  впихнуть в код?

Comment: <span id="Status">Все ок!</span> изменяется вот так